# How to get width and height of mp4 file in php code before playing them

Tags: php, mp4

I need to open file with .mp4 extension in popup. It is playing nicely and all other things are perfectly done. But when that popup is opening. At that time I want it to open with same height and width as of the video. I have that kind of more then 25 videos on my page. So I will store that parameters in code and then use it in javascript when I will open the popup. So I want to know video files width and height before I am playing that file. I want to know these parameters in php.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [php-mp4info](http://code.google.com/p/php-mp4info/) library.

```
include("MP4Info.php");
$info = MP4Info::getInfo('directory/to/file.mp4');
if($info->hasVideo) {
  echo $info->video->width . ' x ' . $info->video->height;
}
```

The $info object is, for example, as follows:

```
stdClass Object
(
  [hasVideo] => 1
  [hasAudio] => 1
  [video] => stdClass Object
    (
      [width] => 480
      [height] => 272
      [codec] => 224
      [codecStr] => H.264
    )
  [audio] => stdClass Object
    (
      [codec] => 224
      [codecStr] => AAC
    )
  [duration] => 6
)
```

Comment: My video is on amazons3 server. So by giving its path it is giving error 0x2a000000-* in stbl :(

Comment: Tried id out but got an error: "0x66726565-free in root". I guess its a bit outdated

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [FF-MPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/). You can use it either via sys calls or using FF-MPEG extension for PHP which is located there http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

Here is the way to get some meta information from the video using FF-MPEG-PHP:

```
$video = new ffmpeg_movie($filePath);

$duration = $video->getDuration();
$width    = $video->getFrameWidth();
$height   = $video->getFrameHeight()
```

FF-MPEG also has a bunch of useful features!

Answer (score -1):

I don't wanna install any php extension (it's a disaster work under Windows, especially Windows 64bit), so I use ffprobe and a php (as follows) to get the dimension:

```
$xcmd = '{$ffmpeg-stored-folder}\bin\ffprobe -v error -of flat=s=_ -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height,width '.$filename.' > vdogeom.txt';
exec($xcmd);
$lines = file("vdogeom.txt");
foreach ($lines as $v) eval('$'.$v.';');
}
echo strtoupper(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)).intval(round(filesize($filename) * .0009765625))."K".$streams_stream_0_width."x".$streams_stream_0_height;
```

it will outpts such like as "**WMV540K640x480**"

The only trick here is: "I have to specify full path of the ffprobe exectution file cause my PHP's PATH environment is very bizzare".

Comment: A more simple solution is to return the result as json:
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams out1.mp4